# Delete row using name instead of ID

Tags: java, android

Below is the code that I use to clear all data in my database

```
public Cursor readEntry() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] allColumns = new String[] { data.NAME,
                data._STATUS, data.WEIGHT, data.DATE};

        Cursor c = db.query(data.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;

    }

    public boolean deleteRow(long id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String where = data.UID + "=" + id;
        return db.delete(data.TABLE_NAME, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void DeleteAll(){

        Cursor c = readEntry();
        long id = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data.UID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) id));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();

    }
```

My question is, how can I use NAME instead of using ID, and how do I call the method String? The code above can just call the method data.DeleteAll(); but in a String case, how do I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `id`, with `name`, here you go:

```
 public Cursor readEntry() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] allColumns = new String[] { data.NAME,
                    data._STATUS, data.WEIGHT, data.DATE};

            Cursor c = db.query(data.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null,
                    null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
            }
            return c;

        }

        public boolean deleteRow(String name) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            String where = data.NAME + " = " + "'" + name + "'";
            return db.delete(data.TABLE_NAME, where, null) != 0;
        }

        public void DeleteAll(){

            Cursor c = readEntry();
            long id = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data.NAME);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    deleteRow(c.getString((int) id));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();

        }
```

Comment: @chaos try this: String where = data.NAME + "=" + "'"+name+"'"; - add apostrophes.I use method like this in my application, all around, because I use hashes of elements not their id's to remove them, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public boolean deleteRow(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = data.NAME + "=" + name;
    return db.delete(data.TABLE_NAME, where, null) != 0;
}

public void DeleteAllUsingNames(){

    Cursor c = readEntry();
    long index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data.NAME);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getString((int) index);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();

}
```

Comment: how should i call the method when the button clear is press? its now data.deleteRow, right?

Comment: If your `data` variable is the object then yes, you can call `data.deleteRow("my string")`  and it will delete all rows which have the value `"my string"` on its `data.NAME` column`

Comment: i used your method, it works, but it didn't delete the first data inside my table, it only delete the second data and so on

Comment: make sure the column value is exactly the same as the passed parameter

Comment: how can i delete all the data? i really have no idea,i'm new to android

Answer (score 0):

You'll do something as follows:

```
public boolean deleteRow(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = data.NAME + "=" + name;
    return db.delete(data.TABLE_NAME, where, null) != 0;
}
```